# Azure Synapse ingest pipeline with ForEach activity on multiple database tables (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, azure-synapse, data-ingestion

I am trying to ingest several tables incrementally in a pipeline on Azure Synapse using a ForEach Activity.

I have defined a variable as an array of strings. Each string corresponds to the name of a table that I want to query inside the ForEach and copy data from it.

My basic problem is how to pass as the table name at a SELECT query at the source of the Copy Activity, the @item that iterates in the ForEach.

*My connection to the MySQL database is established via ODBC.

Comment: Do you have use Query option in source settings?

Comment: Yeah I have used it but I was trying the following but was not working:
SET @t = 'table_name'
SET @q = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ',@t);
PREPARE st FROM @q;
EXECUTE st;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;

Comment: Why are you setting a variable for table_name in the query? Is it not coming from for-each item

Comment: The for each items are coming from a variable array that I have created and they are strings. I have thought adding a Lookup activity and then a Filter activity to take the specific tables that I want. But If I can just set the names of the tables I want to ingest, why do it dynamically?

Comment: Could you specify the requirements again? Do you want to copy only specific tables using filter activity?

Comment: I have a MySQL DB and connecting via ODBC to Synapse. The DB has 42 tables, I want to ingest only 7 of them, incrementally (on time intervals). I have created a pipeline where: **(1)** I set an array variable at Synapse, that contains the names of my tables ['table_1',...] as string values. **(2)** I use this array variable to iterate inside the ForEach activity that my Copy Activity resides. **(3)** At copy activity I use a Lookup activity to get the latest watermark value (incremental loading) and query each table that I have defined at the array variable, to get the rows that I want.

Comment: Try this way
`select * from @{item()} where datet > '@{activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow. datet}'`

Comment: Replace lookup activity details with your lookup activity details and check if this helps

Comment: It worked! I was writing @item() instead of @{item()}. Thank you very much! Can you place it as an answer below, so that if someone faces the same problem, can find it?

Comment: Sure. I will post as answer

Answer (score 1):

[image]Let's say you have two tables named as dimcustomer,dimpersondetail.

1. You can put these two values in a array-type variable
   2.you can use the command @concat('select * from ',item()) in the source query.
   Please refer to the screenshots attached.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, seems to work, but I have one more question. As I said above I load the data of each table incrementally. If I want to add at the : @concat('SELECT * FROM ',item(),' WHERE Datetime > ',**activity('Lookup_watermark_value').output.firstRow.WatermarkValue**,';')
how do I pass the activity output as a string without messing the item() too (I have tried string() function but did not work).

Comment: U can follow the approach given by aswin as your requirement is incremental load. Inside the lookup you

Answer (score 0):

In the copy activity which is inside the for-each activity, instead of giving query as `select * from @item()`, give `select * from {@item()}`.

I tried to repro this in my environment. Below are the steps.

- A variable named **list** is created and two sample table names T3, T4 are given as default value.

[image]

- In for each activity Items, `@variables('list')` is given

[image]

- Inside for each activity, a lookup activity and copy activity is added.

[image]

- In copy activity, Query is given as
  `select * from @{item()} where datet > '@{activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow. datet}`

[image]

- All activities inside for-each got executed successfully.

[image]